# How to use special charcters like (*) in dotenv file

Tags: yaml, dotenv, express-gateway

I would like to use * in dotenv (.env) file as my host for an application is based on subdomains, like (*.lvh.me).

I tried to use characters like URL=/*/.lvh.me in the file and use the environment but it is not working.

TENENT_URL=*.lvh.me

### in gateway

apiEndpoints:
  tenant:
    host: ${TENENT_URL}

I expect it to listen to all the subdomains but it seems not to work, for example if i send request from example.stack.com, it should pass the request to the associated service. Any way i expect the gateway to understand * imported from dotenv file. The gateway seems to work if i hard code but when i pass through dotenv, it is giving error.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a fully reproducible example so I can try it out? Your configuration file seems to be incomplete and I do not fully understand how to move forward :)